# Xamarin.Forms Entry Focus when Unfocused

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I need it so that when the Entry loses focus, the focus returns to the Entry (therefore locking the focus on an Entry).

I did the following code:

```
myEntry.Unfocused += (object sender, FocusEventArgs e) => {
    if (!e.IsFocused)
    {
        ((Entry)sender).Focus();
    }
};
```

It works, but the keyboard stops working - I can't write anything.

Is this a bug? Can someone help me?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish by locking the focus? There may be other ways to accomplish this. Also what platform are you having the keyboard issue on?

Comment: I use on android tablet with usb barcode reader and sometimes the user clicks out, this stops the  workflow. I use for many hours in this screen.

Comment: i needed the same functionality for pin entry which is mandatory. i advise you use another option to make keyboard non-dismissible.

Answer (score 1):

I found that this is a bug xamarin.forms 2.0.0.0. Updated and solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I know on android if you click on an `Entry` and give it focus, the keyboard will appear, and then if you click another element, the `Entry` will lose focus and the keyboard will go away. So by refocussing on the `Entry` when it loses focus, you might be forcing the keyboard to be minimized. This is a total guess though.

What you might be able to do is set the most parent element's `InputTransparent` property to `true` and then only set the `Entry.InputTransparent` property to `false` so that the user is unable to click anything but the `Entry`.

If that does not work, then you could also try adding a transparent `ContentView` that covers everything except the `Entry` and set the `ContentView.InputTransparent` to `true` which would have the same effect.

Comment: Thanks for answer. The keyboard does not disappear. Just do not type anything.Your suggestion did not work.

Comment: I found that this is a bug xamarin.forms 2.0.0.0. Updated and solved the problem.